# File read/write script won't run on other python software

Tags: python, conda, cloud9

I've created a python script in Spyder (Python 3.7). Part of the script includes file opening,writing and appending, like:

```
contactless_file = open('Contactless.txt', 'w')
contactless_file.write(str(30))
contactless_file.close()
etc......
```

These parts of my script work perfectly fine and the files are created, and its contents manipulated. However, for my assessment it needs to work on the Cloud9 IDE on the Amazon web services. but even though my entire scripts runs fine without any errors in Cloud9, the file stuff doesn't seem to do anything. As in like the above code doesn't do anything like it would on Spyder. Any help on what the issue could be?

Comment: Cloud9 IDE may not create and write files, it uses a different mechanism to execute your code alone, something like a temporary readonly workspace only source code you can handle

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Do you have access to any logs?